# Prisma deleteMany with a list of IDs

Tags: javascript, prisma

I'm wondering if there is a way in the Prisma Client to batch delete database records by id.

Something like this doesn't seem to exist:

```
const idsToDelete = [5, 29, 255]

prisma.post.deleteMany({
    where: {
        id: {
            equals: idsToDelete
        }
    }
})
```

The docs allude to the concept of [Scalar List Filters](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#scalar-list-filters), but this doesn't seem to be supported for numeric lists or perhaps isn't supported in `deleteMany`.

Under the hood, I'm hoping for a SQL `DELETE ... WHERE IN` clause. I'd prefer not to:

- Spin up a bunch of individual JS promises
- Use database-specific Prisma features (ok if it's not supported in MongoDB)
- Write SQL directly

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator:

```
    where: {
        id: {
            in: idsToDelete
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. Do you have a link to where it is documented?

Comment: No problem. The client API reference is here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#in